# Using Range Sliders with offline Plotly

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly

I'm having a strange problem with plotly and was hoping that someone has already been trough the same.

I use the Plotly Offline module in python, to generate graphs on real time and present them on a website hosted via Flask. Everything works fine, except now I wanted to put some range sliders in some of the graphs, like the ones described here:
[Python Range Slider Plotly website](https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/)

So after an hour of fiddling around, I just can't get the sliders on range buttons to appear. I even tried copying and pasting the example code they show on that page, but i still get a normal graph with no sliders.

Already tried to update my plotly.js file, it is now on v1.9.0, but still no range sliders showing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my case, since I was using Python, I did upgraded Python to version 3.4.0 and it solved the issue.